# Kaspersky blocks my node.js website images

Tags: node.js

one user says that İ'm getting error;

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 499 (Request has been forbidden by antivirus) wentworth-miller-14015611293982427.jpg
```

After that i also installed kaspersky and i got same error code it says that this website harmful for your system , my web site is kimkimdir.tv.

After hours , i found something maybe **important** , when i enter my web site with ip address

```
http://146.148.31.90:8080/
```

There is no any anti-virus problem , what should i do ?

Comment: i am developing an application with devexpress js controls and on callback of spreadsheet i receive "http://localhost:53280/F2706819-DA9A-5B42-AB8D-27F72C2CC7C8/A0783931-EFBA-4442-9A7A-237E1151DD36/from 400 (Request has been forbidden by antivirus)"

i have kaspersky

Comment: oh it was anti banner feature blocking this. when disabled, works fine

Comment: Maybe it's trying to block the image because it is called `wentworth-miller-14015611293982427.jpg`, kaspersky doesnt like like wentworth miller :D

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling Anti Banner feature. it seems antivirus is blocking some specific types of ajax calls.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue with a user having Kaspersky Antivirus which was blocking ajax requests from tag named as bank. Antivirus (mainly Kaspersky) looks for specific words like BANK, etc in your web pages and block ajax calls or other server requests related to those keywords to protect your data. It does same with jQuery files and does not allow them to run citing security issues. Possible solutions - either remove those keywords like bank from the webpage or if it happens with a specific user/users then a browser console error is generated. It can be allowed by clicking on the browser's console error on user end and enabling it from there.

Answer (score -1):

Kaspersky offers free online service to scan small files (up to 5 MB I believe). Use it, and scan the file you are trying to serve, that will give you more information.

I highly doubt it has anything to do with node.js, thus I would start from verifying the actual file against that antivirus.

Comment: i scan all files there is no any problem , i think it's about express middlewares codes , i will research it

Comment: Moreover , on localhost there is no any alert

Comment: Whats the URL to the Kaspersky web services? I cant find it. If there is some online tool for scanning .js files I would like to use it.

Comment: For what it's worth: Kaspersky had a problem with the word 'Bank' in a partialview, dropdownlist, in a jquery dialog box. On the main page it was fine. Hope it help someone in future.

Comment: I tried to upload a file by Robert Shiller which contained financial terms and numbers. Pausing the antivirus for a minute I was allowed to upload the file.